# Throwing exception and it's messages

Tags: c++, exception, clion

I'm new to using `CLion` and try to write a simple program to understand how it works. I'm on `Windows 8 + cygwin` the program is:

```
int main()
{
    throw std::exception();
}
```

I got in the console the output:

```
C:\....\bin.exe

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Where the messages about the program was aborted or something else? There was nothing, and how should I detect if my program was actually aborted by throwing exception?

Comment: What are your compiler flags?

Comment: "Process finished with exit code 0" That does not make sense.

Comment: @black Why? That was exactly the console output.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe It was compiled with just g++ -c -g main.cpp

Comment: @stella Because an unhandled exception calls `std::terminate` which aborts the execution and it's unlikely to return 0, namely success.

Comment: @stella The '-c' option tells gcc not to link the code but to produce only object files. How's that running?

Comment: @black As far as I incquire it completely depends on runtime. On Linux we got some-abort message, cygwin seems to avoid printing something useful...

Comment: `g++ -c -g main.cpp` doesn't produce a file named `bin.exe` or alter one in any way.

Answer (score 2):

This is done because you don't use `try and catch` instructions and something like stack unwitted happens. In a function if you don't use `catch` instruction, it goes down the stack until it reaches the main function and if there is no `catch`, the program is terminated. If your function throws an exception without `catch` it terminates imediately and it goes back to the caller function. If the caller function is the main function and you don't use `catch`, the program terminate. It goes down the stack and without a `catch` somewhere in this chain of functions it will terminate the program.